# What would be the correct XPath to obtain counterparty with same tag name?

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to figure out what the correct XPath would be to obtain information from this XML doc.

```
<relationships>
    <relationship>
        <person>
            <name>Jane Doe</name>
            <role>Customer</role>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <role>Vendor</role>
        </person>
    </relationship>
</relationships>
```

What I would like to obtain (I'm using PDI), is a table that sort of looks like this.

| Person | Role | Other Person | Other Person Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | Customer | John Doe | Vendor |
| John Doe | Vendor | Jane Doe | Customer |

Seemingly, two rows for every relationship that exists. But because tags share the same name, I don't know how to add the counterparty to the row.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Seems possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7451312/2834978) with XPath 2

Answer (score 0):

Probably this example is too much simplified, so my answer needs more work with your real data, but what I would do is to get the two rows related to person:

| Person | Role |
| --- | --- |
| Jane Doe | Customer |
| John Doe | Vendor |

And afterwards, entry that stream of data twice to a *Join rows (cartesian product)* step with the condition Role <> Role.

The trick to add the stream of data twice would be to use a Select values step, that allows you to rename the columns of **Person** and **Role** to **Another Person** and **Another person role**, and will allow you to get two streams with the same data into the join:
[image: How to input a stream of data twice]

However, the Join rows step can introduce performance issues if you have a lot of data, so maybe you'll have to look for other ways to achieve this.